# CSS "float:right" property equivalent in LinearLayout on android?

Tags: android, css-float, android-linearlayout

On CSS we can write :

```
<div style="float:right"> Text1 </div>
<div style="float:right"> Text2 </div>
```

by this way Text1 will appear on the right ..

I'm trying to do the same with LinearLayout , the View should appear from right to left :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:weightSum="2" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- First Column should be on the right : Text1-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1">...</LinearLayout>
        <!-- Second Column should be on the left : Text2 -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1">...</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: does it appear from top to bottom?

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS mmm,the layout in general does not work , so I'm just trying to simulate float:right using LinearLayout ? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

This may be it

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    >
    <!-- Second Column should be on the left : Text2 -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">...</LinearLayout>
    <!-- First Column should be on the right : Text1-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">...</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have just swap Text2 with Text1 physically ? I can do that , but I don't want ? in CSS we can let the element float to right even if it is written first !

Comment: I also put a gravity on the parent

Comment: you have `layout_gravity="right"` repeated twice in the parent's XML

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is possible with ***LinearLayout***, but you can achieve what you need with a **RelativeLayout** like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In relative layout you can align the "text1" layout container to right side relative to parent (**android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"** or **android:layout_alignParentRight="true"** depending on SDK version compatibility), then you place the "Text2" container LinerLayout at the left side of the Text1 container (**android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"**). If you want to add a 3rd container align right just use this last attribute relative to Text2 container (android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text2") and so on.

Hope this can help you.
It looks like:

[image: Example of right aligned columns layout]

Comment: How can I do a line break? I want a lot of buttons behave like css-float property :)

Comment: @StefanBrendle
You can use this structure inside an horizontal LinerLayout.
`<LinearLayout ···
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout>
    ···
    </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
    ···
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

`gravity="right"` is for the text to float right, like text alignment.

Answer (score -6):

Just set the LinearLayout orientation to Horizontal

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```